# Transferred a javascript function from codepen to replit returning undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wrote this function in codepen then where it was working perfectly when I transferred it over to replit if I call the checkColPlacement function in the solve function I get the following error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘checkColPlacement’)
at pencilArr (/home/runner/boilerplate-project-sudoku-solver/controllers/sudoku-solver.js:163:20)

If I call the function in a console.log with the same initial arguments (puzzleString, a, 1, 1) in the check region function it gives the correct output so it is only undefined when called in the solve function doesn’t make any sense to me.

here is the code of the solve function that is throwing the error:

here is the code where the error is thrown all the arguments are defined i checked them with console log currently the console log is throwing undefined when i try to call the function.

```
solve(puzzleString) {

    
let coordinate = ['a1','a2','a3','a4','a5','a6','a7','a8','a9','b1','b2','b3','b4','b5','b6','b7','b8','b9','c1','c2','c3','c4','c5','c6','c7','c8','c9','d1','d2','d3','d4','d5','d6','d7','d8','d9','e1','e2','e3','e4','e5','e6','e7','e8','e9','f1','f2','f3','f4','f5','f6','f7','f8','f9','g1','g2','g3','g4','g5','g6','g7','g8','g9','h1','h2','h3','h4','h5','h6','h7','h8','h9','i1','i2','i3','i4','i5','i6','i7','i8','i9'] 

/*pencilfunction*/
function pencilArr(puzzleString) {

let pencil = []
for (let j = 0; j <= 80; j++) {
pencil.push([])
if (puzzleString[j] != ".") {
  pencil[j].push("solved")
  pencil[j].push(puzzleString[j])
}
 else {
for (let i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
  console.log(puzzleString)
  console.log(coordinate[j][0])
  console.log(coordinate[j][1])
  console.log(i)
  
  
  console.log(this.checkColPlacement(puzzleString,"a",1, 1))
  
let pencilColumn = this.checkColPlacement(puzzleString, coordinate[j][0], coordinate[j][1], i)
 
let pencilRow = this.checkRowPlacement(puzzleString, coordinate[j][0], coordinate[j][1], i)
let pencilRegion = this.checkRegionPlacement(puzzleString, coordinate[j][0], coordinate[j][1], i)
if (pencilRegion != 'truebox' && pencilColumn != 'truecol' && pencilRow != 'truerow') {
  pencil[j].push(i)
}
}
}
```

here is link to the replit to run the solve function the solve button needs to be hit to just run the checkColPlacement, checkrowplacement, and checkregionplacement functions the check button needs to be hit.

https://replit.com/@CraigMarc/boilerplate-project-sudoku-solver

Comment: How is `pencilArr` used? What do you expect `this` to be and why?

Comment: pencilArr is being used to push an mulitdimensional array for all valid nonconflicting numbers for each cell in a suduko problem.  I still am fairly new to programming and the use of this confuses me but if I place the console log that calls the function into the checkregionplacement function it prints true to the console.  The same console when it is in the solve function returns undefined even though all of the arguments are defined.

Comment: Also when the code was in codepen in pure javascript it worked perfectly so I think it may be a node.js issue

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre]. We need to see concrete _code_.

Comment: its kind of hard to provide a minimum reproducible example.  But got it to work by copying the checkcolplacement, checkrowplacement, and checkregionplacement functions into the solve function. Doing it this way kind of defeats the point of writing functions though. I still dont understand why when the functions were outside of the solve function they were undefined when called in the solve function.